# phpMyAdminでcsvファイルのインポートエラーがでてしまう。

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpMyAdminからエクスポートしたcsvファイルにデータを追加してそれをインポートすると何度やってみてもエラーが生じてしまいます。

カラムの追加などはしていませんし、文字コード、エクセルでのデータ保存も何度も確認してみましたが、毎回エラー：CSV 入力のフィールド数が不正です (行: 1)と表示されてしまいます。

どなたか解決方法をご存知の方、なんでも良いのでご教授いただければと思います。

Comment: わかりませんけど、やはり編集時に文字コードが変わってしまっているとか余計な文字が（改行コードが変換されてるとか）が追加されたということではないですかね。

Comment: エクセルの保存方法と出力の際にクォテーションが削除されていたり、カンマで勝手に区切られていたりでエラーが起こってしまっていたようです。テキストエディタなどで調べてからやってみたりいくつかツールを使いながらやっとできました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpmyadminのcsvエクスポート機能は注意が必要で、記憶が正しければデータにカンマやクオートなどが含まれていると構造が破壊されるようなことがあったと思います。

一度、出力されたcsvを確認するか、公開できるデータを自作してエクスポートしたCSVデータとテーブルの構造を掲載してみてください。

思わぬ箇所でカラムの数が変わっていたりすることがあります。

Comment: 上のコメントのように出力の際の設定のまま保存してもどうしてもエクセルでの保存で違いが出てしまっていました。Cassava Editorなどでクォテーションで囲んで出力したりして統一してからインポートするとうまくいきました。ヒントをいただきまして有難うございました。

Comment: 無事解決したようでよかったです^^